# Using a value from a textbox input on chrome extension as a variable in my content_scripts

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to set a variable from a user textbox input so all my content_scripts can use it based on the amount that is set. In my case, I have a textbox input that is on my chrome extension. This textbox allows the user to input a number. In each of my content_scripts I have a random number generator function that will change based on the number user inputs in the text box. Ideally, I would like it to be without a `set` button. Also, I looked online mostly people are using the `document.getElementById().value` and assign it back to the javascript file, however, I am not getting the value from the DOM, I need to get it from popup.html. All my content_scripts are pretty much the same so I only showed one of them below. Please let me know if you want to see the others.

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "My Page",  
"description": "My Page",  
"version": "1.0",    
"permissions": [
    "tabs", 
    "https://mywebpage.com/*", 
    "storage"
],  

"browser_action": { 
    "default_icon": {
        "30": "images/icons/30.png",
        "48": "images/icons/48.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html"  
},

"icons": {
    "16": "images/icons/16.png",
    "20": "images/icons/20.png",
    "30": "images/icons/30.png",
    "48": "images/icons/48.png",
    "128": "images/icons/128.png"
}
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>  
<body>  
<input type="text" class="delay" name="delay" placeholder="Delay(s)"> 
<input type="button" value="set" onclick=" ">
<button class ="button button0" button id="clickactivity">Button</button>
<button class ="button button2" button id="clickactivity2">Button</button>
<button class ="button button5" button id="clickactivity5">Button</button>    
<script src="popup.js"></script> 
</body>
```

popup.js

```
function injectTheScript() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, 
function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "content_script.js"});
});
var delay = document.getElementById('delay').value; //added
chrome.storage.local.set({'delay': delay});         //added
}

function injectTheScript2() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, 
function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "content_script2.js"});
});
}

function injectTheScript5() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, 
function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "content_script5.js"});
    });
}
document.getElementById('clickactivity').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript);
document.getElementById('clickactivity2').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript2);
document.getElementById('clickactivity5').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript5);
```

content_script.js:

```
var delay = "";                                      //added
chrome.storage.local.get(delay, function(result){    //added
    delay = result.delay;                            //added
    console.log("delay is: " + result.delay)         //added
});

var userInputNum = //how can I get this value from popup.html
var delayMilliSeconds = Math.floor((Math.random() * userInputNum) + 1)

function outputNumber() {
    console.log ("your variable is: " + userInputNum );
}

outputNumber();
```

Comment: Simply use chrome.storage.local

Comment: @wOxxOm I updated my code to use `chrome.storage.local` but the console outputs it as undefined.  Am i missing something

Comment: Callbacks in chrome API are asynchronous so chrome.storage.local.get only sends a request to the API and exits without returning anything, your code continues to run and uses the undefined value, then the value is retrieved in the main browser process, and the callback is invoked. The solution is to put the code that depends on the value into the callback, see also [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)